# What would happen if I disabled compiz on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu

Would disabling compiz have any possible negative effects on Ubuntu?

I believe I need to disable it because it is too resource-intensive.

Comment: +1 for the question, resulting in completely different recommendations in its answers... :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Less eye candy, that's about it. If you liked the video acceleration feature, that is fairly useful though.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it would! Compiz, running without even a single extra plugin, makes the windows move more smoothly by using the graphics card instead of the processor. Without it, moving a window across another will produce artifacts as the window struggles to redraw fast enough to make it unnoticable. It's hardly a major con, but if you **can** run compiz, I'd recommend it just for that.

Answer (score 0):

You will get a lot of benefits :)

- a much more usable window switcher (alt+tab)
- a snappier system
- less problems when developing or using OpenGL applications
- you will look more professional!